# Android tutorial errors

Tags: java, android

I've borrowed the following code from Wei-Meng Lee's "Beginning Android Application Development":

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table contacts (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + "name text not null, email text not null);";
    private final Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    public DBAdapter (Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }
    
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            try {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
}
```

There's more but I'm trying to simplify.

I get the following errors:

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>
> Syntax error on token ")", { expected after this token DBAdapter.java

at the end of `onUpgrade`

> Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody DBAdapter.java
>
> Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody DBAdapter.java

at the end of `onCreate`

I'm new to Android apps so could somebody please help me understand these messages?

Here's what Eclipse is displaying:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just inserting a " } "?

Comment: it looks cross are grayed out so error is removed ? try clean and built

Comment: I needed to hit the save button to update all my faffing edits!

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the error, not just the grayed out ones?

Comment: There is no error, all is right, you doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are messages from the compiler telling you that your braces `{}` and/or parentheses `()` are unbalanced in the file.  If you copied/pasted this code, make sure you didn't miss a brace at the end or something like that.  The code that you've posted looks balanced, so it must be further down in the file.

HTH

Comment: Those gray x markers in the screenshot don't denote an existing error in Eclipse, they mark a previous error that has since been corrected.  Current errors are marked red.

Comment: Actually just pasted the other way, from SO, and the grey 'x''s were gone (after Ctrl-S). Which led me to conclude the error messages weren't as up to date as I had perceived. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding public before the constructor

```
DatabaseHelper(Context context)
```

should be

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as seen above, a brace is needed. Especially if you just copy/pasted codes. Right-click the error, click "Go To", and add/remove (depending on your issue) the required token.